The use of articles in front of singular nouns
Help me, please, crack this puzzle from the book.
A teacher is introducing articles to school kids and says: "If we mean something definite, we put the in front of a noun in the singular, if this something isn't defined, we put a/an".
After that he shows a pen and asks: "What's this?"
A kid: "It's the pen".
The teacher: "Why did you put the?"
The kid: "Because, firstly, there's only one pen, secondly, we all see the same pen, so it is more than defined".
What logical mistake has the kid made in explaining his choice of the article?

What do you think? What have you tried in order to find the answer for yourself?

The teacher's 'explanation' is lacking quite a lot, so maybe the kid should not take all the blame.

The teacher's explanation is wrong. In this context, we use "the" when we're referring to something that has previously been identified. Since no previous mention of that pen occurred, it doesn't apply.

It's simply that the teacher's explanation is insufficient, especially about what "definite" means.

Of course, I know the right answer which is A.

But since everyone in the room sees this and only pen, doesn't the notion of uniqueness apply here?

It's entirely possible that everyone in the class knew there was only one pen: maybe the pupils were too young to be allowed pens and had to use pencils.

@Avidlearner The kid can say, " "This is the pen  our teacher uses for correction."

The question What is this? wants to know what kind of thing it is, and in English, to express X is member of class Y (trying to make that as wooden as possible) we say It is a Y not "It is the Y".

It is a pen.

Second, for a subject to become definite in a speech-act, the speaker must refer to it by its name with a determiner.  It is its epistemological definiteness that matters, not its ontological definiteness.

Class, this pen I'm holding up for you to see was given to me by a stranger.

The pen had ontological definiteness ever since it was manufactured, even while it was tucked away in the teacher's pocket. It achieves epistemological definiteness in a speech-act only when it is presented to the listener by its name with a determiner, as the focus of the speech-act.

Class, a stranger walked up to me and handed me a pen.  [neither the stranger nor the pen has definiteness yet] The pen was made of solid gold and the stranger had a gold tooth. The gold tooth glinted when she smiled.

If you think those are big words, too big for kids to understand, don't even bother trying to explain to them what definiteness is.

Thanks, TimR, well explained!
